# YES/NO Column No Option for Require that this column contains information:

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column

I want to create a column with Yes/No option but I want it to be required that his has to be filled.

However, I dont see the option for "Require that this column contains information: "
I can only find if a use the choice option when  creating a column

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is designed. Yes No column gives you single Checkbox. When Selected it is 'Yes' and when not selected it is 'No'. So either way it is mandatory. If user has not selected it means he wanted to select No.  You can also set default value which controls by default it would be selected or not.

[image]

Hope this helps...Happy coding..!!

Comment: the users dont consider that when uploading files.  I quess I stick with the choice option

Answer (score 0):

It’s the default behavior.

When create a Yes/No column, we need to select the default value which only has Yes and No option. If user not selects any value when he creates an item, the column will be populated with default value.